# Codeigniter userdata session is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, user-data

When I set the session using set_userdata and check that at the other page, everything is setted well excepting userdata...
I use `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());` and code says

> array(5) { ["session_id"]=> string(32) "7195e5aea1695762492bf85d44112120" ["ip_address"]=> string(13) "xxx.xxx.x.xxx" ["user_agent"]=> string(120) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.3" ["last_activity"]=> int(1414848680) ["user_data"]=> string(0) "" }

user_data part is empty.

Here is my code
(application/controllers/login.php)

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    function index(){
        $this->load->model('Join_model');
        $this->load->view('head');
        if($this->input->post('id')){
            $data = $this->Join_model->gets(array(
               'table'=>'acc_wait_tb',
               'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
               'password'=>$this->input->post('password'),
            ));
            if($data == true){
                $dd = $this->db->get_where('acc_wait_tb', array('id'=>$this->input->post('id')))->row();
                $new_data = array(
                    'user_id'=>$dd->id,
                    'name'=>$dd->name,
                    'email'=>$dd->email,
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($new_data);
                echo "<script>
                    location.href='/index.php/main';
                    </script>";
            }else if($data == false){
                echo "<script>alert('Login Fail.');</script>";
                $this->load->view('log_main');
                $this->load->view('footer');
            }
        }else{
            $this->load->view('log_main');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }
}
```

and application/views/nav.php

```
var_dump($data);
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');?>
<?php if($user_id != ""): ?>
<p class="navbar-text pull-right" style="margin-right:30px;">Hi,
  <a class="navbar-link" href=""><?=$this->session->userdata('name')?></a>
</p>
<?endif;?>
```

and application/config/config.php

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'asdfqwerertydfghcvbnsdfgqwerxcvb';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'sess_cookie_name'    = the name you want for the cookie
| 'sess_expiration'     = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|   by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.
| 'sess_expire_on_close'  = Whether to cause the session to expire automatically
|   when the browser window is closed
| 'sess_encrypt_cookie'   = Whether to encrypt the cookie
| 'sess_use_database'   = Whether to save the session data to a database
| 'sess_table_name'     = The name of the session database table
| 'sess_match_ip'     = Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data
| 'sess_match_useragent'  = Whether to match the User Agent when reading the session data
| 'sess_time_to_update'   = how many seconds between CI refreshing Session Information
|
*/
$config['sess_cookie_name']   = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']    = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']    = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix' = Set a prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain' = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'   =  Typically will be a forward slash
| 'cookie_secure' =  Cookies will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
|
*/
$config['cookie_prefix']  = "";
$config['cookie_domain']  = "";
$config['cookie_path']    = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']  = TRUE
```

Please! help me! This error makes me crazy! Please...!
(I try to solve this calling userdata in controller and send data to the view using `$this->load->view('nav.php',$data);` But it didn't work...)

Comment: I have tested your code and its ok.try to debug it whats wrong.write var_dump($this->session->userdata); die() after line $this->session->set_userdata($new_data);and check if it sets your session data.If not then problem may be at you query where its not getting data.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, In my case after successful login i am setting user_data in session and just after echo that whole session data which is fine but after reload page the user_data variable shows empty value .... Have You got any solution for this....?

Answer (score 0):

are you printing the userdata in the view or the controller? Try printing it in the controller. I feel in the view the $this is not the same as in the controller which could be the cause of the issue. You may have to pass $new_data to the view. In addition instead of

```
echo "<script>
location.href='/index.php/main';
</script>";
```

you could use

```
redirect(main);
```

which redirects server side

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the session class?

$this->load->library('session');

I always set session in the autoload. But when I forget I run in this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong because I do not know where your code is running, but if you are localhost you may find browsers refusing your cookie. also you have

```
$config['cookie_secure']  = TRUE
```

and 'cookie_secure' =  Cookies will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.